# Test results from build id

Tags: azure-pipelines

As part of my scheduled builds, I run and publish multiple tests which are having different test run titles.

My scenario is that during the release pipeline, I want to fetch the test summary for each of the test run titles that were published for the build from which release is being created.

Which Azure DevOps API or combination of APIs can be used to achieve this?

Thanks,
Anubhav.

Comment: The description is confusng, are you looking for the way that you can get the result list of your tests? If so, you can use the REST Api `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results?api-version=5.1`, more information at [Results - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

Comment: @YangShen-MSFT: Yes, but only thing I do not know the test run id, but I know the build id for which the tests ran.

Comment: Sorry for long time no response. If you want to get the test run id, `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?api-version=5.1` should be what you want, check [Runs - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) for more information.

Comment: @YangShen-MSFT: Can I get the test runs that are associated with a given build id?

Comment: The test result of the build is stored in test runs, if you want to get the test result then what you need is test runs, maybe `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/report?api-version=5.1-preview.2` from [Report - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/report/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) might help relate to buildid, get the test runs from the build report and then use the test run to get the test result.

Answer (score 1):

Having BuildId,

step1: use this api [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/ResultDetailsByBuild?buildId={buildId}](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/test/ResultDetailsByBuild?buildId=%7BbuildId%7D) ,  get run id through this api rather than from URL.

step2: GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs/{runId}?api-version=6.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/test/runs/%7BrunId%7D?api-version=6.0) to get Test run results in detail.

for [reference](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/394858/vsts-vstest-build-details-tests-tab-error-tfswebap.html)

hope it would be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

The test result of the build is stored in test runs, so you need the test runs if you want the test results.

Use `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/report?api-version=5.1-preview.2` from [Report - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/report/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get the test runs.

Then use `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results?api-version=5.1` from [Results - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get the test results.

Or you can use `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?api-version=5.1` from [Runs - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) directly get the test runs.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not get the published unit test results as part of the build, when I give the build id to the Report API. What am I missing?

Comment: Ok. I think I figured out. https://vstmr.dev.azure.com/{org}/{proj}/_apis/testresults/resultdetailsbybuild?buildId={id}&groupBy=TestRun

Comment: Great! May i ask where you found the solution? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, by investigating the api calls in the network tab in developer tools window of the browser, while clicking on the Test Results tab of the build in AzDo

Comment: Genius! That should be the solution. Can you please post this solution and mark it as the answer? This should help more people who met the same issue.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in C# using the [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/) nuget package with this code:

```cs
    int buildId = <buildId>;
    
    var baseUri = new Uri("https://dev.azure.com/<your org>");
    string project = "<your project>";
    var credential = new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, "<your PAT>");
    
    var buildClient = new BuildHttpClient(baseUri, credential);
    var build = await buildClient.GetBuildAsync(project, buildId);
    
    var testManagementClient = new TestManagementHttpClient(baseUri, credential);
    var testRuns = await testManagementClient.GetTestRunsAsync(project, build.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
```